# For loop not iterating in the function- Language: Python

Tags: function, for-loop

I am new in learning coding and started with python. I trying to define a function which will iterate over each item in the list and return the item. However, the code is only returning the first item.

ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

def second_char(y):
for char in y:
return char
ky= second_char(ex_lst)
print(ky)

Highly appreciate your input. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Please can you edit your post to include all relevant information in **textual format**. Screenshots of code relevant to your question will almost certainly invite downvotes and non-participation.

Comment: Add a language tag please. We don't all code in the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is simply returning the first element of the list, Why?
Because as soon as the compiler reaches the **return** statement it simply returns the value.

In your case

```
def second_char(y):
    for char in y:
    return char
```

As you can observe from this, the loop is going to call the return statement in its first iteration which will eventually return 1st element.

To make it right you've to make another list and append all the elements of ***ex_list***  into ***list*** and then return that.

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

def second_char(y):
    list = [] //creating a local list
    for x in y:
     list.append(x)  // storing the ex_list in list and returning it 
    return list
ky= second_char(ex_lst)
print(ky)
```